# is there a easy way to insert for viewing purposes one/few column into ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a perfect view currently with a a list of items displayed.

business team, being slick they are, want to insert a promotional program right in between two ng-repeated list elements.

best way to do this? any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show an element after repeated item with specified index.

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  {{item}}
  <span ng-show="$index==2">Ad</span>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, but this way i'd need to compile one version of this for each ng-repeat. is there a cleaner way?